# what is the meaning of this std::string constructor

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stdstring

Today I tried to study some piece of code and I am stuck with this line.

```
std::vector<std::string(SomeClassInterface::*)()> ListOfFnPointers;
```

what is the meaning of this std::string constructor? I went through [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) but I have no idea what it means.

It is used in the code as,

```
if (!ListOfFnPointers.empty())
{
    std::vector<std::string> StringList;
    for (auto Fn : ListOfFnPointers)
    {
        StringList.push_back((pSomeClassObj->*Fn)());
    }
    ...
}
```

1. What that declaration means?
2. what exactly this function doing with `pSomeClassObj->*Fn`?

Comment: Hint: the name `ListOfFnPointers` is important.

Comment: Thanks man. I never thought about function pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `std::string` constructor.

`std::string(SomeClassInterface::*)()` is type of [pointer to member function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions), the member function belongs to class `SomeClassInterface`, returns `std::string`, takes no parameters.

`->*` is [pointer-to-member access operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_pointer-to-member_access_operators) (and also `.*`). `(pSomeClassObj->*Fn)()` will call the member function on `pSomeClassObj`, which is supposed to be a pointer with type `SomeClassInterface*`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a constructor it's a pointer to function without parameters returning std::string.

```
for (auto Fn : ListOfFnPointers)
{
    StringList.push_back((pSomeClassObj->*Fn)());
}
```

Push back's above are working because (pSomeClassObj->*Fn)() is a call to these functions and result is std::string.

UPDATED:

1. It is declaration of std::vector of pointers to function. Each function belongs to SomeClassInterface, takes no parameters and return std::string.
2. In case of this code (pSomeClassObj->*Fn)() calls the function of objects pSomeClassObj where Fn is a pointer to this function and member of pSomeClassObj.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `C++11`,you can write code like this:

```
using FunctionPointer = std::string (SomeClassInterface::*) ();
std::vector<FunctionPointer> ListOfFnPointers;
```

you can read this link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias